# Delphi XE3 App with ActiveX / COM objects

Tags: delphi, com, activex, delphi-xe3

I'm a bit confused on something, being quite a while since I've used external controls. Basically, I'm writing a small test app with Delphi XE3 which uses an ActiveX control. A TLB file is generated as usual. I have tested on two machines (an Acer notebook and a Dell Latitude 10). When I test on my desktop Windows machine I get an error traceable to the OCX file. I was under the impression that the TLB.pas file was all that was needed to instantiate the control. Do I also need to install and register the OCX file ? Does COM component need to be distributed with its .DLL file ? TIA for your anticipated help.

Brian Corll

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that I am using an Ole call to CrystalRuntime.Application to get the whole thing going.

Comment: See [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The type library only describes **how** to call the library. The .pas file generated from the type library also only describes how to call the library. That's all compile time. At run time when you actually call the library, you need the library to be registered and present.

So yes, you'll need to distribute and register the library.